# passing drop downlist selected value to Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

i have a dropdown list in my view which is populated through model . i want to pass the selected value to
ajax link.

```
     <select name="dd" id="dd">
              @foreach (var item in Model)
              {
                    <option value="@item.cid" >
                            @item.cname</option>
              }
                   </select>   


        @Ajax.ActionLink("Submit", "Someaction" , new { id =  } , new                   AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })


        <div id="result"></div>
```

how should i route selected value of dropdown ? please help

Answer (score 1):

Selected change action is the client side event, so you cannot handle this event with helpers. But you can use somethink like this:

```
<select name="dd" id="dd">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
        <option value="@item.cid" >@item.cname</option>
   }
</select>
```

script

```
$("#dd").change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();

    // in here you have ddl value
    // you can pass this parameter with 
    // ajax and update your result div

    $.ajax({
        url : 'Home/SomeAction',
        data : { selected : selectedValue },
        ...
        success : function(result){
            $("#result").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

controller

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int selected)
{
    // selected is the selected value of DDL...

    //return Json/PartialView
}
```